# Is there an alternative to FFT to extract spectral density within specific frequency ranges?

Tags: signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

I am looking for an algorithm that allows me to get additional/ consistent information of the low frequency spectral components of a signal.
So far I have been using Fast fourier transforms, the issue is that these algorithms are generally chaotic in the lower end of the frequency spectrum, and provide a lot of information that is not useful to me.
for reference, I am working with ~2500 samples and I'm only interested in the first 100 elements of the FFT (from 0 frequency to 1/25th of the nyquist frequency).
Are you aware of any algorithms that can provide a more detailed discrete breakdown of the low frequency spectral components of a signal at the cost of ignoring the higher frequency ones?

Comment: I would try using a filter, e.g. [Kaiser filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiser_window) to filter out unwanted frequencies

Comment: So, I do want the frequency breakdown, i'm just looking for higher resolution in lower frequencies

Comment: There are several. I would start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUSIC_(algorithm)).